# SD card not getting formatted

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, formatting, sd-card

I have a 32 GB micro SD card which got *kind of corrupted* during file transferring from my computer. Now, I am not able to format it.

**On Linux**:

I have tried **Disks** utility of Linux, it has no effect on the SD card or its partitions. Sometimes it shows the error: **error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)**

[image: Disks]

**GParted** shows that it has completed the formatting successfully, but when it refreshes, the SD card comes to its previous state, unaffected.

Below is the output of **fsck**/**dosfsck** (which claims to fix the issue, but actually it does not):

```
snehasish@asus-x200ma:~$ sudo fsck /dev/sdb1
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action
? 1
/Attack on Titan - Season 2/[Cleo]Attack_on_Titan_S2_-_09_(Dual Audio_10bit_720p_x265).mkv
  File size is 209715200 bytes, cluster chain length is > 209715200 bytes.
  Truncating file to 209715200 bytes.
Free cluster summary wrong (189446 vs. really 189430)
1) Correct
2) Don't correct
? 1
Perform changes ? (y/n) y
/dev/sdb1: 5469 files, 778346/967776 clusters
```

By default the SD card is getting mounted in read-only mode, and sometimes only the defected folder is labelled read-only. I have tried to delete all the contents of the SD card by remounting it in writable mode, but the contents come back when I re-insert the card.

I have also tried to re-write the whole SD card with **dd** using the following command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=16MB

dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb1 bs=16MB
```

It completes normally, but the SD card is again unaffected.

The utility **parted** did not proved to be useful either.

**On Windows:**

I have tried formatting on Windows from the **File Explorer**, it says "**Windows was unable to complete the format**" for both quick and full format.

**Disk Management** also showed the same error message when I tried to format from there.

**DISKPART** also failed to format it.

**CHKDSK** detected the corrupted file, but in the process of fixing the issue, it ended normally after showing "**6% completed...**".

On windows, I am not able to delete the corrupted folder as well. It does not show any error message. It just does nothing when I tried to delete the folder.

All I want is to **format the SD card and reuse it**. I have already taken back up, so I don't want any data to be recovered. I have tried many other ways of deleting the contents/formatting which I don't remember. Any help in fixing this ghostly issue will be much appreciated.

Comment: The card is dead. Replace it.

Comment: Well, it's possible that the SD is really corrupted. SD cards can't last forever, the number of overwrites is much lower than in SSDs.